# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; near 'WHERE e.company_id = 1

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run Left Join in MYSQL

```
SELECT e.id, e.employee_code, concat(e.first_name,' ',e.last_name) Fullname, e.email, e.department_id, 
CASE
    WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 0 THEN "DRAFT"
    WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 1 THEN "AWAITING APPROVAL"
    WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 2 THEN "NOT APPROVED"
    WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 3 THEN "APPROVED"
ELSE "NOT STARTED"
END AS line_manager_mid_year_approved,
e.grade_level_name, e.work_location_id, e.line_manager_id
FROM hr_employees e
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT employee_id, line_manager_mid_year_approved FROM appraisal_goals GROUP BY employee_id) a
ON a.employee_id = e.id
WHERE a.is_active = 1
WHERE e.company_id = 1 
AND e.hr_status = 0 
AND e.validation_status = 'VALID'
AND e.employee_type_code NOT IN (4,5);
```

I got this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'WHERE e.company_id = 1 AND e.hr_status = 0 AND
> e.validation_status = 'VALID'' at line 15

When I remove WHERE a.is_active = 1, the error is no more there. But I really need that particular where clause.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you're using multiple `WHERE` clauses.

Try changing the second `WHERE` to an `AND`:

```sql
SELECT e.id, e.employee_code, concat(e.first_name,' ',e.last_name) Fullname, e.email, e.department_id, 
CASE
    WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 0 THEN "DRAFT"
    WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 1 THEN "AWAITING APPROVAL"
    WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 2 THEN "NOT APPROVED"
    WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 3 THEN "APPROVED"
ELSE "NOT STARTED"
END AS line_manager_mid_year_approved,
e.grade_level_name, e.work_location_id, e.line_manager_id
FROM hr_employees e
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT employee_id, line_manager_mid_year_approved FROM appraisal_goals GROUP BY employee_id) a
ON a.employee_id = e.id
WHERE a.is_active = 1
AND e.company_id = 1 
AND e.hr_status = 0 
AND e.validation_status = 'VALID'
AND e.employee_type_code NOT IN (4,5);
```

Alternatively you could have the `WHERE a.is_active = 1` be part of the `ON` clause like:

```sql
SELECT e.id, e.employee_code, concat(e.first_name,' ',e.last_name) Fullname, e.email, e.department_id, 
CASE
    WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 0 THEN "DRAFT"
    WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 1 THEN "AWAITING APPROVAL"
    WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 2 THEN "NOT APPROVED"
    WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 3 THEN "APPROVED"
ELSE "NOT STARTED"
END AS line_manager_mid_year_approved,
e.grade_level_name, e.work_location_id, e.line_manager_id
FROM hr_employees e
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT employee_id, line_manager_mid_year_approved FROM appraisal_goals GROUP BY employee_id) a
ON a.employee_id = e.id
AND a.is_active = 1
WHERE e.company_id = 1 
AND e.hr_status = 0 
AND e.validation_status = 'VALID'
AND e.employee_type_code NOT IN (4,5);
```

Comment: When I did that, I got this error:  #1054 - Unknown column 'a.is_active' in 'where clause'
. But it exists in appraisal_goals

Comment: It may exists in the table, but not in the subquery you named `a`